# Wndows Server 2008 DNS - occasional error in browser "unsupported compression"

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system

I am just entering the world of server admin and configuration and thought that I was successfully on my way to having a functional Windows 2008 server configured for my home network.  The problem is that since I changed my network to use DNS and DHCP provided through the server I am encountering an occasional problem on my Win7 machine.  I have an AT&T Uverse router which I was not able to disable DHCP for but I set it to only hand out a single IP (which happens to coincide with the server).
The error I am seeing in the browser is essentially that the configuration is invalid or it is an unsupported form of compression.
I am obviously connected now but via an iOS device which seems to work fine.
I'm not sure if this is simply related to a DNS server configuration or something else entirely so I didn't post any details of configuration since I'm not sure where to start.  Please ask questions though for clarification.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Some websites compress the page when sending it from server to browser, to make it faster. It sounds like the error you see is related to that, and nothing particularly to do with DNS Windows 2008.

1. Which computer are you on when you see the error? Using the server, or browsing to the server?
2. Does this happen for websites hosted on the 2008 server, or websites out on the internet?
3. Does it always happen for some sites and is always OK for other sites?
4. Does it happen if you change browsers? Try FireFox or Chrome.

Comment: 1. I am on my Win7 machine. 2. Websites on the Internet. 3. If I continue to refresh the browser it eventually displays the page. 4. It seems to happen more in IE, but I have seen it in Firefox.  I have Chrome installed but have not verified.

Comment: Curious. Can you make the problem go away completely all, e.g. if you unplug or turn the 2008 server off, if you use Google DNS settings on your Win7 machine? I mean, is it definitely tied to the 2008 server somehow? Also, can you get a copy/screenshot/photo of the error message and upload it to (text-> pastebin.com / picture -> imgur.com) or similar hosting sites? (imgur has a free iOS app).

Comment: Win7 ipconfig /all : http://i.imgur.com/7uMc9.png and the iOS config : http://i.imgur.com/I66gO.jpg  I have not seen the error again to capture it since it is sporadic.  I will post if/when I can.